# React build working in local but giving error in aws amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, build, production, aws-amplify

build Working perfectly in local but build in aws amplify giving this error

main.f5442d4a91817bdc45ac.chunk.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at Object.30d4618c93dd28193de1 (main.f5442d4a91817bdc45ac.chunk.js:1:142951)
at r (runtime~main.141471ccb067843afe63.js:1:519)
at Module.8b703812aa8ae3c41814 (main.f5442d4a91817bdc45ac.chunk.js:1:1004440)
at r (runtime~main.141471ccb067843afe63.js:1:519)
at Object.1 (main.f5442d4a91817bdc45ac.chunk.js:1:25474)
at r (runtime~main.141471ccb067843afe63.js:1:519)
at d (runtime~main.141471ccb067843afe63.js:1:387)
at Array.f [as push] (runtime~main.141471ccb067843afe63.js:1:250)
at main.f5442d4a91817bdc45ac.chunk.js:1:47

i try to debug but unfortunately i could not found the solution or what is the exact problem